# Use the directional derivative to estimate the change in $f(x,y)=\cos\pi xy+xy^2$ as point $(-1,-1)$ moves distance of $0.1$ along vector $i+j$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Use the directional derivative to estimate how much $f(x,y)=\cos\pi xy+xy^2$ will change if the point $P$ is moved from $(-1,-1)$ a distance of $0.1$ along the vector $i+j$

I don't know how to solve this problem can someone please give me some hints about what the problem wants?

the answer in my textbook is $0.15\sqrt2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't start solving it because I don't know how and where to start

Comment: The problem says, "Use the directional derivative..."  So step one:  Compute the directional derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\nabla f=(-\pi y\sin\pi xy+y^2,-\pi x\sin\pi xy+2xy)$$
$$(\nabla f)(-1,-1)=(1,2)$$
The vector of length $0.1$ in the stated direction is $\frac{0.1}{\sqrt2}(1,1)$. The estimated change is then the directional derivative computed with this displacement vector, i.e. the dot product with $\nabla f$:
$$\frac{0.1}{\sqrt2}(1,2)\cdot(1,1)=\frac{0.3}{\sqrt2}=\frac{0.3\sqrt2}2=0.15\sqrt2$$